# Print to Zebra Printer by using IP Adress

Tags: windows, printing, zebra-printer

Sorry to ask you a second question, but i need your help.
I tried to print in my office to the Zebra printer. I get the IP adress of the Network printer, and i can visit the Site in my browser. for example: 10.0.0.01 -> goes to zebra printer.

Now i want to print some files, by using the IP adress. If it works, i want to print with the internet Browser. The printer isn't listed in devices and printer.

I dont't have the permission for the PrintServer. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have the permission _from your admins_ to print directly without the printserver?

Comment: I think not so, how can i find it out?